# Getting invalid GET request from client, possible hack?

Tags: php

Im seeing some strange activity in my apache logs. They look like this:

```
80.246.130.179  GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1  
80.246.130.179  GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1
80.246.130.179  GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
and so on...
```

Its a GET request to my PHP file. The weird thing is that I dont have "apple-touch-icon.png" or "favicon.ico" anywhere in my files so they result in 404. I tried blocking based on IP address but he keeps changing the IP address, all the calls are from Israel. So before blocking an entire country I would like to know weather this is "evil" behavior. Is he creating time out sessions to do stuff??

Im on a shared server, no database and PHP code is not worth "hacking". So my question is: Why is he/she doing this?

Comment: Please read what `apple-touch-icon` and `favicon` is, before banning this IP's...

Comment: @Glavić He is making a hundreds calls, not one of them is valid...They all come from Isreal and the IP keeps changing, why is that?

Comment: Occam's Razor: This is not worth doing, therefore noone is doing it. You are looking at well-known behavior of widely used software.

Comment: IP's are changing because he has dynamic IP or there are just different persons. And maybe he is the only one connecting to your site with iDevice or smth... But again, this doesn't matter, best thing here is for you to support touch-icon and favicon.

Comment: @Jon But why does it only come from Isreal, and why from different IP address everytime I block the old one?

Comment: @Glavić There is not ONE SINGLE VALID REQEUST FROM THAT COUNTRY, THEY ALL RESULT IN 404.......................

Comment: @Youss: I have no idea, nor does anyone else except *perhaps* from the person(s) who control the software that makes these requests. That should be obvious. Not knowing why something happens does not mean it happens on purpose.

Comment: Are you looking access logs or error logs?

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, Im not going to pay attention to it anymore, wel Im going to try anyway...

Comment: @Murat Çorlu Im looking at access logs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe these are hack attempts. These calls are generated automatically by some devices, for example:

```
80.246.130.179  GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1
```

Is what happens when a user saves you website to homescreen on an iDevice, the iDevice is looking for an icon on your server and if it doesn't find it it gives a screenshot of the site as the homescreen icon. The apple specifications state that the filename must be `apple-touch-icon.png` and be located on the root of your site.

The other one:

```
80.246.130.179  GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1
```

Is when browsers try to automatically get your favicon. Maybe when someone is trying to add your site to favourites..

Comment: Can you please explain some more...I dont get it..

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Comment: and there: http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/appletou.htm

Comment: @Vlad Why is there not a single valid request or "visit" from Isreal other than the 404's?

Comment: @Yotam Omer YES I HAVE CHECKED all of them, there are hundreds, not one of them is VALID. Its going on for 3 whole weeks now

Comment: @Yotam Omer I live in Amsterdam, host is also in Amsterdam, been advertising with adwords worldwide

Comment: @Yotam Omer I dont think that is necessary. I didnt know sites like hola.org exited...Thanks for your time, Im just going to forget about it, looking at all the answers I dont think there is any harm here

Answer (score 3):

Browsers checks favicon files from root url. And IOS safari checks apple-touch-icon.png automatically. You can ignore it or put some good graphics.

Comment: But why does it happen only from Isreal??? There are no other (authentic) calls made from that country

Comment: Why does he keep changing his IP adress???

Comment: I don't know your website's content and I don't know how many visitors do you have but maybe your website is being popular in Israel. Maybe some Israeli people shared links from your site, and you saw these logs. But these requests doesn't seems a type of hacking.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Im starting to get it...I think its automated requests...But what troubled me is that the IP address kept changing, how can someone afford so many IP adresses...

Comment: Maybe it isn't just one person, maybe, as @MuratÇorlu says, your page is getting popular in Israel, If I were you I would start by creating a favicon and the apple-touch-icon